# Which affine format to use in Rasterstats zonal_stats?

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, affine-transformation, rasterstats

I am working with the [Rasterstats](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/index.html) package to run [zonal statistics](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/manual.html#zonal-statistics) on two raster datasets. The documentation calls for the following:

```
import rasterio
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

with rasterio.open('tests/data/slope.tif') as src:
    affine = src.affine
    array = src.read(1)
zs = zonal_stats('tests/data/polygons.shp', array, affine=affine)
```

However, `src.affine` is no longer supported in Rasterio. Instead, the documentation recommends using `src.transform`, which yields something like:

```
Affine(1.0, 0.0, 670625.0016573452,
       0.0, -1.0, 5282947.795216726)
```

When I do something like the following, I get an error:

```
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

dataset = rasterio.open('/path/to/image.tif')
affine = dataset.transform * (0,0) # upper left corner
zs = zonal_stats(segments, ndvi, affine=affine, stats="mean")
```

---

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

---

What affine format does the Rasterstats `zonal_stats` function require?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results of `dataset.transform` and `dataset.affine` are equals (see [Migrating to Rasterio 1.0: affine.Affine() vs. GDAL-style geotransforms](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/migrating-to-v1.html))

With rasterio version < 1 (affine = [affine](https://github.com/sgillies/affine) transform, transform = GDAL-style geotransforms,

```
import rasterio 
rasterio.__version__
'0.36.0'
with rasterio.open('slope.tif') as src:
   affine = src.affine
   transform = src.transform
affine
Affine(25.52514657450613, 0.0, 244300.61494985913,
   0.0, -25.52514657450613, 1000868.7876863468)
print(affine)
| 25.53, 0.00, 244300.61|
| 0.00,-25.53, 1000868.79|
| 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|
transform
[244300.61494985913, 25.52514657450613, 0.0, 1000868.7876863468, 0.0, -25.52514657450613]
```

And the conversion

```
from affine import Affine
# or
from rasterio import Affine
aff = Affine.from_gdal(*transform)
aff
Affine(25.52514657450613, 0.0, 244300.61494985913,
   0.0, -25.52514657450613, 1000868.7876863468)
gda = aff.to_gdal()
gda
(244300.61494985913, 25.52514657450613, 0.0, 1000868.7876863468, 0.0, -25.52514657450613)
```

With rasterio version > 1.0b (transform = [affine](https://github.com/sgillies/affine) transform)

```
import rasterio
rasterio.__version__
'1.0.13'
with rasterio.open('slope.tif') as src:
    transform = src.transform
transform
Affine(25.52514657450613, 0.0, 244300.61494985913,
   0.0, -25.52514657450613, 1000868.7876863468)
print(transform)
| 25.53, 0.00, 244300.61|
| 0.00,-25.53, 1000868.79|
| 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|
transform.to_gdal()
(244300.61494985913, 25.52514657450613, 0.0, 1000868.7876863468, 0.0, -25.52514657450613)
```